Page routes are prepended to API URLS when running Cypress tests in CI environment
So I have a problem with Cypress where the routes defined in my stubbed api's aren't matching the routes Cypress is recording from my app

In the picture above /patient-lists/patient is the page route and /v1/auth/session is the API url, because of this the stubbed API isn't being recognised by Cypress and my tests are failing.
I'm not sure wether the issue is with Cypress, the CI environment (Circle CI using a similar config to whats in the Cypress RWA), or with my app (Vite, running on npm run dev)
If anyone has any ideas or pointers I'd be very grateful.
Addtional Info:
Cypress config
import fs from 'fs';

import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    env: {
        url: 'http://localhost:9000',
        apiUrlV1: 'http://localhost:9000/v1',
        apiUrlV2: 'http://localhost:9000/v2',
        test_user_username: '***',
        test_user_password: '***',
        test_user_email: '***',
    },
    e2e: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
        fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
        specPattern: 'cypress/tests/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
        supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.ts',
        viewportHeight: 960,
        viewportWidth: 1536,
        testIsolation: true,
        setupNodeEvents(on) {
            on('after:spec', (spec: Cypress.Spec, results: CypressCommandLine.RunResult) => {
                if (results && results.video) {
                    // Do we have failures for any retry attempts?
                    const failures = results.tests.some((test) =>
                        test.attempts.some((attempt) => attempt.state === 'failed')
                    );
                    if (!failures) {
                        // delete the video if the spec passed and no tests retried
                        fs.unlinkSync(results.video);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    },
    retries: {
        // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
        // Default is 0
        runMode: 3,
        // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
        // Default is 0
        openMode: 0,
    },
    video: true,
});

Vite Config
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');
    return {
        plugins: [react(), svgr(), tsconfigPaths()],
        base: env.VITE_URL_PREFIX,
        server: {
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                '/api': {
                    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
                },
            },
        },
        build: {
            sourcemap: true,
        },
        test: {
            globals: true,
            environment: 'jsdom',
            setupFiles: './src/lib/vitest/setup.ts',
        },
    };
});


What is the intercept code, and what is the app code that calls the API?
